# C# Regular Expression to validate a date?

Tags: c#, regex, validation, date

I am trying to validate a date entered into a text box. There is an input mask on the textbox which forces input of xx/xx/xxxx. I am trying to use a regular expression validator to enforce that a correct date is entered. I am not skilled in RegEx bascially at all.  My co-worker found this one on the internet but I can't really tell what it's doing.

Does this look right? Seems overly complicated...

```
(^((((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))|([1-9]))\x2F(((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))|([1-9]))\x2F(([0-9]{2})|(((19)|([2]([0]{1})))([0-9]{2}))))$)
```

Does anyone know of a less complex expression that essentially does what I need?

Comment: This has been addressed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669741/date-regex) post. See if it helps.

Answer (score 35):

Why not use one of the methods available in the [`System.DateTime` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods.aspx)? You could use [`DateTime.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) (**edit:** [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) is probably the right suggestion) to accomplish the validation.

Comment: And DateTime.TryParseExact() may be more appropriate depending on your exact needs.

Comment: What if I wanna make sure the the date is correct at the button click itself?

Comment: +1 dont reinvent the wheel. Additionally, regex should not be use for validating the _parsed value_ of a string, only the _form_ of the string, to ensure that you can parse it. If it parses a proper pattern, you should not need `TryParse`.

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

```
DateTime dt;

bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "08/30/2009",
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dt);
```

Answer (score 7):

This would be correct regular expression to use for date format dd/mm/yyyy

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

Comment: Not exactly - you need to make the initial zero optional or it won't match single digit day values like 2/12/2012.

^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$

Answer (score 3):

The above regular expression is correct for dd/mm/yyyy format. the expression is

```
(^((((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))|([1-9]))\x2F(((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))|([1-9]))\x2F(([0-9]{2})|(((19)|([2]([0]{1})))([0-9]{2}))))$)
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can use CompareValidator instead of RegularExpressionValidator. It goes like this:

`<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtIssueDate" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Format" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="valGroup1"></asp:CompareValidator>`

Answer (score 2):

Kettenbach had a problem.
His co-worker suggested using regexs.
Kettenbach then had two problems.

As others have said, use `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` on a custom validator and save yourself the nightmare that is regex :)

Comment: Regexes aren't inherently evil. They need to be used judiciously, though. They work great for a certain class of text parsing problems.

Comment: oh I never said they were evil, per say... But they are on a level with cats.

Comment: Please attribute the above statement to Jamie Zawinski.

Answer (score 1):

Last answer is actually the correct way to do. Use `DateTime.TryParse`.

Example:

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse(Textbox1.Text,out dt))
{
 Label1.Text = "Invalid date format";
}
```

Comment: TryParse actually returns true if the parse was successful, so your notification of invalid date format should be in the else of that condition.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but couldn't you use `DateTime.Parse` or [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) to check that the date is correct?

Either that or use a `DateTime` control to make sure it's impossible to enter data that isn't a DateTime. There's lots of JavaScript out there on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a CustomValidator and use the override the ServerValidate method to check the TryParse!

Answer (score 0):

```
([0][1-9]|[1][0-9|][2][0-9]|[3][0-1])\/([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])\/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

for dd/mm/yyyy (year can be from 1000 to 2999)

or

(([0][1-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[1-9]|[1][0-9])/([0][1-9]|[1][0-2]|[1-9])/([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]))

which includes d/m/yy (e.g. 1/12/82)