# Regular expression to validate different dates

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, datetime

I have the below regular expression to validate date:

```
^([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])/20\d{2} ?(([0]?\d)|(1[0-2])):[0-5]\d(:[0-5]\d)? ?(AM|am|PM|pm)$
```

This is validating date as : `mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS am`.

But some customers has got the different date format for ex: `mm-dd-yyyy HH:MM:SS am.`

can somebody advise how to change my regular expression to match all formats?

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression? You can use DateTime.TryParseExact(value, formats... where formats = { "yyyyMMdd", "ddMMyyyy", "dd MMMM yyyy" }; for example.

Comment: _...how to change my regular expression to match all formats..._ **all** formats or **both** formats that you provided? How about validating, let's say, February 31st?

Comment: Why not just use a datepicker control so that you don't have to contend with different date formats? Or dropdown controls for each date component?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Regular Expression to validate a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359188/c-sharp-regular-expression-to-validate-a-date)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with regex, just replace the forward slashes in your regex with hyphens.

i.e. `^([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])-20\d{2} ?(([0]?\d)|(1[0-2])):[0-5]\d(:[0-5]\d)? ?(AM|am|PM|pm)$`