# How can I remove all timestamps from HTML string in javascript, using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, timestamp

I have some HTML code stored in a variable:

```
var htmlString = ...
```

I want to remove all timestamps that are in this string, of the form (example): `2021-04-26 04:15:04.309`. Something like:

```
var htmlStringWithoutTimestamps = removeTimestamps(htmlString)
```

Hoy can I do this? Maybe with regex?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Could you share an example or two?

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057739/3807365). The logic is pretty understandable.

```js
function removeTimestamps(htmlString) {
  var reg = /[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}/g
  return htmlString.replace(reg, "");

}
var htmlString = 'hello 2021-04-26 04:15:04.309! or:AB2021-11-11 11:11:11.222CD'
var htmlStringWithoutTimestamps = removeTimestamps(htmlString)

console.log(htmlStringWithoutTimestamps)
```