# Swap month with day in date string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date string in format dd/MM/yyyy and I want to create a Date object from this string. `new Date(dd/MM/yyyy)` won't work..

I have this code, that obviously does not work:

```
function createDateObject(value){
    try{
        return new Date(value.split('/').**swap(0, 1)**.join('/'));
    }
    catch(){
        return null;
    }
}

createDateObject('31/01/2014') => Fri Jan 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Local Daylight Time)
```

Which is the simplest way to do this?

I wouldn't like to create a lot of temp variables if I could do it in one single line...

Comment: You could use Momentjs (http://momentjs.com) or Sugar (http://sugarjs.com/dates) for date manipulation.

Comment: Just concatenate the array elements you get from splitting in the right order …

Comment: just right what i wanted! thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe I used `Array.reverse` and it worked with my test cases.

Just replaced **swap with reverse():

```
function createDateObject(value) {
    try {
        return new Date(value.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
    }
    catch(e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It creates the Date correctly, but let invalid dates to be created, such as Feb/30/2014.
So I also have to validate string using this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897331/986862):

```
function createDateObject(value) {
    try {
        string formatted = value.split('/').reverse().join('/');
        return isValidDate(formatted) ? new Date(formatted) : null;
    } catch(e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Since your question is how to swap month with day in a string (`dd/mm/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy`), this is the answer:

```
var dateString = "25/04/1987";
dateString = dateString.substr(3, 2)+"/"+dateString.substr(0, 2)+"/"+dateString.substr(6, 4);
```

However, if you would like to create a `new Date()` object, you have to change the string according to the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (`dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`):

```
var dateString = "25/04/1987";
dateString = dateString.substr(6, 4)+"-"+dateString.substr(3, 2)+"-"+dateString.substr(0, 2);
var date = new Date(dateString);
```

Comment: If you want to refine a date including the hours/minutes `"25/04/1987 14:52"` you can add `+ds.substr(10, 15)`, so something like: `dateString.substr(6, 4)+"-"+dateString.substr(3, 2)+"-"+dateString.substr(0, 2)+ds.substr(10, 15)`

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
value = value.split("/");
var d = new Date(value[2], parseInt(value[1], 10)-1, value[0]);
```

You have to subtract `1` from month because JavaScript counts months from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to pass a string to the [date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) it is recommend that you use the [ISO8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Try this.

```
function createDateObject(value) {
    try {
        var parts = value.split('/');
        return new Date(parts[2] + "-" + parts[1] + "-" + parts[0]);
    } catch () {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to swich your items like this :

```
function createDateObject(value){
  var splitDate = value.split("/");
  return new Date(splitDate[2],splitDate[1],splitDate[0]);
}
```