# how to add if else condition into an array in javascript (edited)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

i have this piece of code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function CompareDates(id)
{
var months = new Array(12);
 months[1]=  "Jan";
 months[2] = "Feb";
 months[3] = "Mar";
 months[4] = "Apr";
 months[5] = "May";
 months[6] = "Jun";
 months[7] = "Jul";
 months[8]=  "Aug";
 months[9] = "Sep";
 months[10] = "Oct";
 months[11] = "Nov";
 months[12] = "Dec";


var d = new Date(id);

var retVal =d.getDate()+' '+ months[d.getDate()]+' '+d.getFullYear()
return retVal; } 

</script>
```

and calendar tag:

```
<p:calendar 
id="testDate" 
styleClass="calendar"
pattern="d MMM yyyy"
maxlength="10"
onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');"
onchange="$(this).val(CompareDates($(this).val()))"
>
<p:watermark for="testDate" value="dd/mmm/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

and i need to add an if/else statement in it so that if date is >31 and months is >12, the date will return 'false' as for now,

it returns 'NaN undefined NaN'

Can someone tell me where and how should i add the condition in?

I did this:

```
var d = new Date(id);

if (d.getDate > '31' || months > '12'){
return false;

} else {
var retVal =d.getDate()+' '+ months[d.getDate()]+' '+d.getFullYear()
return retVal; } 
}
```

and result is, even if the date is within the limit it'll still return false.

Comment: What is the value of "id"?

Comment: Yes.. What is coming from id??

Comment: i'm sorry i'm not quite sure because that piece of code was provided by another user here from stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Here this will work:

```
function compareDate(dateValue){
    if(arguments.length){
        date = dateValue.split("/") //when date is entered in DD/MM/YYYY format. We split days months and year
        days = date[0] //get DD
        month = date[1] //get MM
        year = date[2] //get YYYY
        d = new Date();
        total_days = new Date(d.getYear(),d.getMonth()+1,0).getDate()
        if(days > 0 && days <= total_days && month >0 && month <= 12){
            //your success message
        }else{
            //your error message like date not valid
        }
    }else{
        //no date specified
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi zee, i am trying to convert user's input of month-number to month-name therefore i made my month index to start from 1.

Comment: I mistook || to be (and), instead of (or), as pointed out by someone earlier.

Comment: yeah but getMonth() function returns months index from zero only. You can check. Jan is returned as 0.

Comment: do you mean it should be months[d.getMonth()] instead?

Comment: i need 'Jan' to be returned, instead of 0 though, i changed it to 'getMonth' and my array to start from 0, and when i entered '01', 'Dec' is returned.

Comment: Yes. You are correct.  months[d.getMonth()] will do it. Will return Jan, instead of 0. I dont understand why do you need to use, because you are getting both month and date from javascript functions. They wont be wrong. So your if will always be false.

Comment: hi.. i don't exactly understand what you mean by i am getting both month and date from javascript....?

Comment: When you use if(d.getDate() >31 && month> 12 ) d.getDate() > 31 will always be false because no month is of 32 days. Also you are using second condition month > 12, it is unclear where month's value is coming from. You are trying to check month array against 12 which is wrong.

Comment: if that's the case how should i set a condition which will return false if the user keys in any invalid dates? instead of system returning 'NaN'

Comment: var total_month = new Date(d.getYear(),d.getMonth()+1,0).getDate(). if(user_provided_month > total_month && user_provided_month > months.length ) { //throw error } else { //ok }

Comment: Here, the above code checks if the user provided wrong days in month or wrong no of months

Comment: so my 'user_provided_month' will be 'months' am i right? according to my codes?

Comment: i do not understand this part: **d.getYear(),d.getMonth()+1,0).getDate().** could you kindly explain the logic of this sentence for me? thank you very much!

Comment: and everytime i use '&&', i get this error: **The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference**

Comment: yes.... d.getYear(),d.getMonth()+1,0).getDate().It gets the total number of days for current month. I need to see the code once before i can actually help. Would you mind?

Comment: alright done, this two pieces of code are all i have.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with case:

```
switch (d) {
case 29:
    alert (29 days);
    break;
case 30:
    alert (30 days);
    break;
case 31:
    alert (31 days);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a `Date` object `d` from `id` parameter.  In this way, it is impossible that Date `d` to be outside the date and month range... so probably your checking is not necessary.

Just in case you still need an answer, I would say:

```
if (d.getDate > '31' || months > '12'){
return false;
} else { //...
```

Note that `months` is an array.  Probably you meant `d.getMonth()` rather than `months`.
`d.getDate` need to be `d.getDate()`.

Additional note: `getMonth()` method returns 0-11, i.e. 0 for January and 11 for December.  You will probably need to adjust for the checking.

Comment: hi! i need the array to start from [1] because i am supposed to convert user's input of month number to month name.

Comment: Simple way - make the array start from [0] i.e. `Months[0]="Jan"; Months[1]="Feb"` etc.  This doesn't look good at the beginning, but you will appreciate it as programmers prefer array to start from 0.  A not-so-good-looking way: report `Months[d.getMonth()+1]`.

Comment: You can further simply your code for the Array declaration part as `var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];` rather than those 13 lines from `var months = new Array(12);` to `months[12] = "Dec";`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make couple of changes to your code:

1. Change array values starting from index 0 and so on. 
   **months[0]=  "Jan";** instead of months[1]=  "Jan";
2. Date object already has getMonth() method use it to publish month

   var retVal =d.getDate()+' '+ **months[d.getMonth()]**+' '+d.getFullYear();

   1. No additional condition required.

**Suggestions::**

1. you can use shorthand method to compress your code
   **var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");**
2. I dont grasp why you have used (id)...I believe it is not required. But let me know if missed anything. Will be glad to answer.

**Here is the complete code:**

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
CompareDates();
function CompareDates()
{
var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
var d = new Date();
var retVal =d.getDate()+' '+ months[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getFullYear();
alert(retVal);
return retVal; 
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Hi! this piece of code was provided by another user from here and he included the (id) therefore i did not make any changes to it, though it did help me achieve what i initially needed. I have made the changes accordingly but now, no matter what i manually type for the month, it'll still return the current month :( would you like to see the complete piece of code for better reference?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking.

```
> function CompareDates(id) {
```

What is *id*? Is it a string or a time value? Function names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors, so better to use:

```
function compareDates() {
```

Also, this doesn't seem to compare dates, is the name still appropriate? Or maybe it's a work in progress. :-)

```
> var months = new Array(12);
> months[1]= "Jan";
  ...
> months[12] = "Dec";
```

Consider using an array literal. It seems you are trying to convert a Date object month number to the English month abbreviation. In that case, make the array zero indexed (as others have suggested):

```
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
              'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

> var d = new Date(id);
```

Hopefully *id* is a time value since letting the Date constructor parse strings is problematic and inconsistent in browsers. I'll assume that it's creating a suitable Date object.

```
> var retVal =d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getDate()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear()
```

To get the appropriate month name:

```
var retVal = d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
```

however it's not common to use a space as a separator, "-" and "/" are more common.

As has also been said, once *id* is converted to a Date, it will always fit the parameters for a valid date. If it can't be converted to a valid date, it will evaluate to `NaN`.

However, if *id* is a string (and it should not be, see above) like "23/5/2014" then you can vlidate it using the answers to [How to validate a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date).

#### Edit

So it seems *id* is a string. You can't specify a format for *Date.parse*, it may accept particular strings but it's generally unreliable so manually parse the string. Assuming it's in d/m/y format:

```
// Expects d/m/y
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
}
```

The date can be validated using:

```
// Expects d/m/y
function isValidDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = parseDMY(s);
  return !!d && d.getFullYear() == b[2] && d.getDate() == b[0];
}

console.log(isValidDate('29/2/2014')); // false
console.log(isValidDate('29/2/2016')); // true
```

The above will return either true or false depending on whether it is passed a valid date in d/m/y format. For some browsers, the above will fail if the year is from 1 to 99 as they assume such dates are 20th century and make them 1901 to 1999.

If you wish to also handle dates in the first century, use:

```
// Expects d/m/y
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  d.setFullYear(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d;
}
```

Comment: Hi!! thanks SO much for your detailed explanation of my array, i'm really new at coding but for my internship, i was asked to do it. and that code was provided by one of you experts here :) now i understand it better and the problem for me now is that my supervisor does not wish to see 'NaN' when it can't be converted.

Comment: How can i change that to something else? and also, i have tried to make the array zero indexed but it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: it will only return months 'nov' and 'dec'

Comment: sorry my mistake, it does work. however the format that it converts from is mm/dd/yyyy, so if i input '01/03/2013' it'll return '3 Jan 2013' even though i have specified the pattern to be d MMM yyyy. and it only happened after i changed months[d.getDate] to months[d.getDate]. could you kindly explain to me why is this the case? your help is greatly appreciated!