# Regular expression in Javascript to test for various dates

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression in javascript that can test for dates with the following formats:

- yyyy-MM-dd  (Example: 2014-12-31)
- dd.MM.yyyy  (Example: 31.12.2014)
- dd.MM.yy    (Example: 31.12.14)
- ddMMyyyy    (Example: 12312014)
- ddMMyy      (Example: 123114)
- dd.M.yy       (Example: 12.6.14)
- dd.M.yyyy     (Example: 12.6.2014)

Sorry, but I am really terrible at regular expressions. This is probably a breeze for a pro. Thanks a milion.

Comment: One of these is not like the others... Namely, the first one is in a completely different format to the others, making a single regex difficult to use.

Comment: You cannot (and shouldn't) use regular expressions to validate dates. Is `99.33.8888` a valid date?

Comment: The last two examples don't match their signature. (they are MMddyyyy)

Comment: `ddMMyyyy (Example: 12312014)` is incorrect: '31' is the day, and '12' is the month, so it should be `MMddyyyy` or the example should be rewritten. `ddMMyy (Example: 123114)` is incorrect: same reason. And if you're consistent with your "Example" formatting, '12' is always representing the MONTH, not the DAY, and either `31` or `6` should be the DAY. Could you modify the post to reflect the correct format (or the correct Example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first pattern is too different from the others to be meaningfully merged. So: `\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d`

For the others, you are allowing an optional `.` as a separator, and either two- or four-digit years. So you have: `\d\d(\.?)\d\d?\1\d\d(?:\d\d)?`

The `\1` in the above is to basically repeat the `(\.?)`'s result - ie. a dot if there was a dot before, or nothing if not.

Result:

```
/^(?:\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d|\d\d(\.?)\d\d?\1\d\d(?:\d\d)?)$/
```

Comment: So are you saying that your result can only be used for the last 4 examples but not for the first one? I thought regular expressions allowed some kind of ORing.

Comment: @AndroidDev I broke the problem into two problems, then joined them together with the `|` - it is there ;)

Comment: @AndroidDev Forgot to make the last two digits optional so it wasn't accepting two-digit years. Try now.

Comment: I added two more examples at the end. Would you be so kind as to include those as well :-)

Comment: Now supports single-digit months.

Comment: That's fantastic. Would it be too much to ask whether it's possible to limit days to a number between 1 and 31 and months between 1 and 12? @thg435 does raise a point about having invalid days and months.

Comment: @AndroidDev Sadly not. Well, possibly, but only if you're willing to write a monstrous regex to handle all possible cases, in particular which years are leap years ;) Use this regex to validate that your input is a date, then try to process that date and see if it makes sense.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/tH1cV7 shows a regex that handles leap years, although the format is different than these requested. It could be left up for an exercise for the user ;).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date)? You don't want to use regex for stuff like this, since aforementioned 99.33.8888 isn't a date.

This clever function could solve your problem:

```
var isDate_ = function(input) {
    var status = false;
    if (!input || input.length <= 0) {
      status = false;
    } else {
      var result = new Date(input);
      if (result == 'Invalid Date') {
        status = false;
      } else {
        status = true;
      }
    }
    return status;
  }
```

Edit: I forgot you need to find something to validate. You could just run a simple regex like this: [`[0-9-/\.]{6,10}`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B0-9-/%5C.%5D%7B6,10%7D&input=yyyy-MM-dd%20%28Example:%202014-12-31%29%0Add.MM.yyyy%20%28Example:%2031.12.2014%29%0Add.MM.yy%20%28Example:%2031.12.14%29%0AddMMyyyy%20%28Example:%2012312014%29%0AddMMyy%20%28Example:%20123114%29), which matches all of your examples

Comment: The solution MUST allow for the formatting I specified.

Comment: just remember to validate the regex in some ways.