# I want to check yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm (regular expression)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I Want to form check text like : YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm (Date time)
And I found this ↓

```
                    "regex": /^((((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13578]|1[02])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13456789]|1[012])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](29)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])))$/,
```

It worked.
but this id checked : YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
And cut :ss part (I think)

```
"regex": /^((((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13578]|1[02])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](0[13456789]|1[012])[\/\.-](0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))|(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))[\/\.-](02)[\/\.-](29)\s(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])))$/,
```

It doesn't worked.
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use a regular expression, this should work:

> /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/

It has no limit on range, so someone could put 14 as the month. It only checks that the format you want is exactly followed with any numbers.

Comment: This will allow many invalid date/times to be accepted, such as `9999-13-32 25:61`

Comment: I said that right in my post... It only checks for format, not range.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if a string is a valid time, a better approach is to use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Like so:

```
alert(Date.parse("2001-12-20 20:39"));  // returns 1008841140000
alert(Date.parse("2001-12-50 20:39"));  // returns NaN (sometimes?)
```

If you want to make extra certain the date matches that format, you can output it and check it against the original, like so:

```
Date.parse(y).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") == y
```

Comment: I want to real-time check HTML text form . but Thank you for your answer, I try Date.parse() another function.

Comment: "Better" than what? That format returns `NaN` in Safari, Firefox and a few versions of IE still in use at least. Parsing strings using *Date.parse* (or the Date constructor, which is effectively the same thing) is infamously unreliable, just don't do it. To validate a date using a Date object, see [*How to validate a date?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date).