# DateTime Validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javascript. I am fixing bug programmed by others. I see validation code in javascript as:

```
 function validateTime(str) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$/);
    if (pattern.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it does't validate time:-  22-05-2015

How can it be done?

Comment: It's not clear whether you are trying to validate a date or time: subject "*DateTIme*", function called "*validateTime*", text: "*…doesn't validate time*", example: "*22-05-2015*", which is a date.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*How to validate a date?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date), but maybe not…

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object's `parse` method to verify a date string. 
You can then check if the value of `Date.parse(str)` is equal to `"Invalid Date"` to see if it is malformed. No need for regex at all.

Comment: That only works if the string is in a format that is correctly parsed by the Date function in the browser being used. Until ES5, that was entirely implementation dependent. Now it **should** work for ISO 8601 format dates, but doesn't necessarily. The format in the OP will be treated differently by current browsers in use.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex validates time, not date. To check against date in your format, use this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(19|20)\d\d$/);
```

You can check this pattern here:

https://regex101.com/r/kB5nV2/1

Comment: Thanks alot!! Worked perfectly!!

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett thanks, Indeed I omitted that slash, already put it back in place. As to separator, I assumed OP wants exactly this format, sure it could be enhanced to capture even more formats.

Comment: @n-dru, no problem, fair enough! Prakash, you should pick an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function parseDate(str) {
  var m = str.match(/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/);
  return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2]-1, m[1]) : null;
}
```

The function **validateTime(str)** used in your code is for time validation. Try the **parseDate(str)** for date validation.