# Regular expression for date format MM/DD/YYYY returns false results

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a jquery date picker that pops up everytime I click my textbox(prfm_dtrequest). It returns mm/dd/yyyy format which is the way I want it to be. I need to validate the content of the textbox afterwards to make sure it is in the correct format before loading it into my database when clicking the submit button(#submitform). My code below only returns "is not a valid date" even if I

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>testing</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
              <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
              <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
             <script>
              $(function() {
                $( "#prfm_dtrequest" ).datepicker();
              });
            </script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submitform").click(function(){
                    var daterequested = $("#prfm_dtrequest").val();
                      var dateMMDDYYYRegex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
                        if(dateMMDDYYYRegex.test(dateMMDDYYYRegex)){
                           alert('is a valid date: '+daterequested);
                        }else{
                           alert('is not a valid date: '+daterequested);
                        }
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <body>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                <input type="date" id="prfm_dtrequest" class='txtfld01' name=''><input type="submit" id="submitform" value="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your regex (valid date example: **03/31/1988**):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitform").click(function(){

    /* isValidData source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date */

    function isValidDate(s) {
       var bits = s.split('/');
       var d = new Date(bits[2], bits[0] - 1, bits[1]);
       return d && (d.getMonth() + 1) == bits[0] && d.getDate() == Number(bits[1]);
    }

    var daterequested = $("#prfm_dtrequest").val();
        var dateMMDDYYYRegex = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$";
        if(daterequested.match(dateMMDDYYYRegex) && isValidDate(daterequested)){
            alert('is a valid date: '+daterequested);
        }else{
            alert('is not a valid date: '+daterequested);
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lvs3ogp/3/)

Result:

[image]

Comment: but it's return _valid date_ on any date! for example : 50/50/0000 is a valid date ?!

Comment: returns 23/05/2016 as valid date. it has to be mm/dd/yyyy. thanks

Comment: I need it to accept mm/dd/yyyy format instead of dd/mm/yyyy. Your update code works fine for dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: It is ok now for you? only  mm/dd/yyyy  allowed

Answer (score -1):

Use below regex for mm/dd/yyyy format:

```
    var dateMMDDYYYRegex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    if(dateMMDDYYYRegex.test(dateMMDDYYYRegex)){
       alert('is a valid date: '+daterequested);
    }else{
       alert('is not a valid date: '+daterequested);
    }
```

Comment: it returns invalid format