# Retain and lose focus on Textbox based on validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, textbox

I have a Textbox which will only allow user to input date in `mm-dd-yyyy` format. If the date is valid, the user will be able to move focus out of the textbox but if it's invalid, the focus should remain inside the textbox until the user corrects it. Currently I am using regex to validate the textbox input and I am able to successfully keep focus inside the textbox in case of invalid date. The issue I am facing is, even when I am correcting the invalid date, the focus does not move out of the textbox.

```js
var dateCheck = function() {
    var value = $("#txtbox1").val()


    if (/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(value)) {
        $("#txtbox1").blur();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $("#txtbox1").focus().on('blur', function () {
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="12" class="form-control" onfocusout="dateCheck()" id="txtbox1"/>
```

P.S : Using Datepicker is not part of the requirement, would have been much easier I know. Any leads regarding this would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I have found a working solution and have updated the code above, but this code works only in Chrome and not in IE11

Comment: just as a sidenote, I would consider transforming the date server side. This adds usability.

Comment: @KuebelElch15 any ideas or links where I can explore this possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `else` part. You can use [HTMLElement.blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)
 to remove the focus from the element. You can easily pass `this` element to the function so that you can refer the current element inside the function. I will also suggest you to use `oninput` event instead of `onfocusout`.

Try the following way:

```js
var dateCheck = function(el) {
  var value = $(el).val();
  if (/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(value)) {
    el.blur();
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="12" class="form-control" oninput="dateCheck(this)" id="txtbox1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This snipped checks if the date is valid and if it is correctly formatted.

```js
var dateMMDDYYYRegex = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$";
/* isValidData source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date */

function isValidDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split('/');
  var d = new Date(bits[2], bits[0] - 1, bits[1]);
  return d && (d.getMonth() + 1) == bits[0] && d.getDate() == Number(bits[1]);
}
var dateCheck = function() {
  var value = $("#txtbox1").val();        
  if(value.match(dateMMDDYYYRegex) && isValidDate(value)){
    $("#txtbox1").blur();
    return true;
  } else {
    $("#txtbox1").focus().on('blur', function () {
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="12" class="form-control" onfocusout="dateCheck()" id="txtbox1"/>
```

Personally I would consider using an input mask like [this](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/) one to make it easier for the user to use your code. Also don't forget to validate the date serverside. I would use a libary called [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to phrase the date.

Reference to the code: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954948/regular-expression-for-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy-returns-false-results)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **onblur** event, instead of using onfocusout event. Please refer to the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateCheck = function () {
        var value = $("#txtbox1").val()
        if (/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(value)) {
            $("#txtbox1").blur();
        }
        else {
            $("#txtbox1").focus();
        }
    };
</script>
<input type="text" size="12" class="form-control" onblur="dateCheck()" id="txtbox1" />
```

the output as below:

[image]