# JavaScript From Date To Date Validation issue

Tags: javascript, validation, date, comparison

I referred earlier post for Date comparison from stack overflow - [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) , yet I am not sure where I am wrong . Please guide.

```
function dateValidation(){
    alert("dateValidation");

    var dateFlag=true;

    var fromdate_1=new Date(fYear,fMonth-1,fDate);
    var currentDate_1=new Date();
    var todate_1=new Date(tYear,tMonth-1,tDate);

    alert("fromDate"+fromdate_1);
    alert("toDate"+todate_1);
    alert("currentDate"+currentDate_1);

    if(fDate==null||fMonth==null||fYear==null)
    {
        alert("null");
        dateFlag=false;
        fromDateFlag=false;
    }
    else
    {   
        alert("else");
        if(!isNaN(fromdate_1) && !isNaN(currentDate_1) && !isNaN(todate_1))
        {   
            alert("else 2");
            if(fromdate_1 > currentDate_1)
            {   
                alert("fromDate>currentDate");
                fgcFlag=false;
                dateFlag=false;
            }

            if(todate_1 < fromdate_1)
            {   
                alert("toDate<fromDate");
                fgtFlag=false;
                dateFlag=false;
            }

            if(fromdate_1 > currentDate_1 && todate_1 < fromdate_1)
            {   
                alert("fromDate>currentDate && toDate< fromDate");
                dateFlag=false;
                tlfFlag=false;
            }

            if(fromdate_1 > currentDate_1 && todate_1 > fromdate_1)
            {
                alert("fromDate>currentDate && toDate> fromDate");
                fgcFlag=false;
                dateFlag=false;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("dateFlag"+dateFlag);
    return dateFlag;
}
```

On selection of fromdate - "Aug 1st 2016" and todate - "Aug 25th 2016" and when I invoke the javascript -dateValidation, 
I see the alerts in the below order

1. dateValidation
2. fromDate **"Aug 1st 2016"**
3. toDate **"Aug 16th 2016"**
4. currentDate **"Aug 25th 2016"**
5. else
6. else 2
7. dateFlag **true**

I observe the date comparison is not happening in javascript. 
I am aware
**dates.compare(a,b)**

Returns a number:

- -1 if a < b
- 0 if a = b
- 1 if a > b
- NaN if a or b is an illegal date

Please could anyone point where I am going wrong / what changes must be made ?

Comment: Use the ms after 1970, `Date.getTime()` to compare dates.

Comment: Oh oki.. so it works as expected

Comment: Then it's normal it doesn't work. 25 aug as the current date is bigger than both 1aug and 16 aug. How do you get 25 aug though, since if I copy/paste your code into my console, I get 16 aug 16:33

Comment: Hmm, the logic seems flawed I guess. fromDate (1 aug) is not bigger than currentDate (16 aug), so condition 1,3 and 4 will not trigger. And toDate (25aug) isn't smaller than fromDate (1 aug) either, so condition 2 won't trigger either. So edit your logic to match what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can greatly simplify the date validation, see [*How to validate a date?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date/5812341#5812341). Once you've validated the dates, to see if "today" is in range, you just need `fromDate <= today && today <= toDate`. The comparison operators coerce the Date objects to their time value.

Comment: BTW, it would help greatly if you post the code as a runnable snippet with valid input.

Answer (score 0):

You get *dateFlag true* because that is the value it's initialised to, and all of the *if* tests inside *else2* fail, so the value of *dateFlag* is not changed.

Given:

1. fromDate "Aug 1st 2016"
2. toDate "Aug 16th 2016"
3. currentDate "Aug 25th 2016"

then:

```
fromdate > currentDate     // false
todate   < fromdate        // false
fromdate > currentDate ... // false, second part of test isn't reached
fromdate > currentDate ... // false, second part of test isn't reached
```

So the code does exactly what it's been told to do. If you are trying to see if *currentDate* is between *fromDate* and *toDate*, then:

```
if (fromDate <= currentDate && currentDate <= toDate) {
  // currentDate is in range
}
```

does that in one step. But you haven't said what you are actually trying to do.