# How to determine if the date is full date and year only in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have this regex code below to validate a valid date.

```
function isValidDate(div) {
var reg = /^((0?\d)|(1[012]))\/([012]?\d|30|31)\/\d{1,4}$/;
var regs = /^\/\d{1,4}$/;
var dateField = $(div).val();
if (dateField == "") {
    //alert('Invalid inclusive dates.');
    return false;
} else {
    if (reg.test(dateField) == false && regs.test(dateField) == false) {
      // alert('Invalid inclusive dates.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am testing this code as you can see I have 2 condition in `if (reg.test(dateField) == false && regs.test(dateField) == false) {`. In this line I am testing if the date is full date(1/1/2017) or (2017) only. If I input that two different dates it return false because of the condition. How to achieve this?.

Comment: I'm not sure of what exactly are you asking. Please clarify

Comment: If you just want a regular expression to test patterns for "1/1/2017" or "2017", they can be very much simpler than what you have, e.g `/$\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/` and `/^\d{4}$/`. If you want to also validate the values, that's another story (and should not use a regular expression).

Comment: @Rajesh If user input 1/1/2017 or 2017 it will return as true. otherwise it return false.

Comment: *regs* seems to be testing for "/2017".

Comment: @RobG yes. but I am having trouble in `else` condition

Comment: var dateField = $(div).val(); what does this line mean..? can you pls update if you mean it as a div element or an input field

Comment: `$(div).val();` refer to my id of a datepicker

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*How to validate a date?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date/5812341#5812341). Your issue is with *regs*, there is an erroneous leading slash, it should be `var regs = /^\d{1,4}$/`.

Comment: @RobG if i input year I want to read it as true. For example I input 2 dates `1/1/2017` and year `2017` it should be read as true :(

Comment: @RobG its okay now i added an `else if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make day and month optional:

```
var reg = /^(?:(0?\d|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30|31)\/)?\d{1,4}$/;
//          ^^^                                       ^^
```