# How to check date validation in regex using js?

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am trying to validate date in js ("yyyy/mm/dd") format. After googling I found other date format checked but I can't get in this format.

Any one plz can help me out.

Here is my code.

```
function dateChecker()
{
    var date1, string, re;
    re = new RegExp("\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\{1,2}");

    date1 = document.getElementById("visitDate").value; 
    if(date1.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("showError").innerHTML = "Plz Insert Date";
        document.getElementById("showError").style.color = "red";
    }
    else if(date1.match(re))
    {
        document.getElementById("showError").innerHTML = "Ok";
        document.getElementById("showError").style.color = "red";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("showError").innerHTML = "It is not a date";
        document.getElementById("showError").style.color = "red";
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `re=/\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/` or `re=/^\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}$/` if the whole string should match. The `\{1,2}` is a typo, and if you need to use a constructor notation, then double the backslashes. Still, you do not validate a date this way, just check if the string looks like a date.

Comment: Use moment.js, regex is not best suited for date-validation. In moment.js, you can do something like, isValid function.

Comment: sorry! non of them works for me.

Comment: Also see [*How to validate a date?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date/5812341#5812341).

Comment: If you use momentjs you can just do 
const date = moment('01-01-2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY', true)
date.isValid() // true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `new RegExp` then you must call compile on the resulting regular expression object.

```
re = new RegExp("\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}");
re.compile();
```

Alternatively you could write the regex this way which does not require `compile` to be called.

```
re = /\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/;
```

**EDIT**

Note that the above regex is not correct (ie it can approve invalid dates).  I guess the brief answer is, don't use regex to validate date times.  Use some datetime library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) or [datejs](http://datejs.com).  There is too much logic.  For instance, how do you handle leap years, different months having different number of possible days, etc.  Its just a pain.  Use a library that can parse it, if it cant be parsed, its not a date time.  Trust the library.

However you could get closer with something like this

```
re = /^\d{4}\/(10|11|12|\d)\/((1|2)?\d|30|31)$/;
```

Also if you want to get comfortable with regex, download [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm)

Comment: Thanks, But I am checking date it will valid "9999/99/99"

Comment: see the edit to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = "2017/01/13";
var regex = /^[0-9]{4}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}$/g;
console.log(regex.test(date));    // true
console.log(regex.test("13/01/2017")); //false
console.log(regex.test("2017-01-13")); // false
```