# date validation regex - make leading zeroes optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently use the following regex from http://regexlib.com to validate the incoming date using the pattern YYYY-MM-DD. But the leading zeroes are mandatory and I want it to be optional.

```
((((1[26]|2[048])00)|[12]\d([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48]))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|[12]\d))))|((([12]\d([02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789]))|((1[1345789]|2[1235679])00))-((((0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)))|(02-(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lDaR_Qg3LemyQ-S7)

**[Test case](https://regex101.com/r/cr4wax/1)**

```
2000-01-01
2000-1-1
2000-01-1
2000-1-01
```

are all valid. But only the first test case is accepted, as of now.

Can you please help?

Comment: Just use a simple regex - `\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}`

Comment: Don't use a regular expression at all, see [*How to validate a date?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date/5812341#5812341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this much more simply using a function rather than a regular expression. The following is much simpler to understand and therefore maintain (though it shouldn't ever need any), and is a lot less code that the regular expression in the OP.

```js
function isValidISODate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0],--b[1],b[2]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1];
}

// Some tests
['2016-1-1','2016-01-01','2016-2-29','2016-02-30'].forEach(
   s=>console.log(s + ': ' + isValidISODate(s))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a number optional by adding them the number of permitted ocurrences `{0,1}`. That is `{1,2}` to accept either 1 character or 2.

A simple version:

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}
```

**Edit:** Your version is easy to "fix". Simply add `{0,1}` after the compulsory 0:

```
// Before.
((((0[13578]
// After.
((((0{0,1}[13578]
```

**Edit2:** As @Toto has said `{0,1}` is the same as `?`

```
((((0?[13578]
```

Comment: I think this is a more complex Regex designed to not only check the YYYY-MM-DD format but to actually check that it is a legitimate date.

Comment: @Someone edited to reflect the result with his version

Answer (score 0):

Using this regex - '\d+-[0-2]* [0-9]-[0-3]* [0-9]' may help .

Comment: No, this regex allows years with infinite numbers, but month and day musst have two chars - which is exactly not what he want

Comment: What question are you answering?