# Sorting a table by number not alphabetically

Tags: javascript

found this simple solution here on w3

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_desc

it works great but sorts the table by A to Z even if you put numbers in the table. So if you have values like: 1, 2, 3, 11 ... it will sort it 1, 11, 2, 3. I actualy hope this is a duplicate question but I was not able to find the answer here. How can I get the sorting function to sort no number value? ... and maybe you also know to to get it to sort by date?

Comment: Are you looking to do this on the client or server? Your question is tagged with both JS and PHP.

Comment: @iainn you know what, you're right. I was in a hurry... yeah... i should be js only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the part where the `asc` or `dsc` comparison is done in the example you shared.

If you look at the `sortTable()` function in the `<script>` of the example - you are comparing values as strings, hence the numbers are sorted like -  1, 11, 2, 23, 3

```
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
     //the x.innerHTML returns string
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
```

You have to do something like this:

```
   if (parseInt(x.innerHTML) > parseInt(y.innerHTML)) {
      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
```

Now you'll be comparing numbers, I suggest create a separate function `sortNumbers` for the number columns or keep the same function `sortTable(0, type)` -> `type` params can take in text or number and sort accordingly.

Let me know if you need more explanation. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the linked example, see this part:

```
  if (dir == "asc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

It's working with innerHTML, which is always a string, so the comparison operators performs comparison of strings (where "11" < "2"). To make it compare numeric content as actual numbers, you must first convert it to numbers (if the content is not a number, parseFloat results in a `NaN` object, which is checked for by the `isNaN()` function):

```
  var xNumeric = parseFloat(x.innerHTML);
  var yNumeric = parseFloat(y.innerHTML);

  if (dir == "asc") {
    if (!isNaN(xNumeric) && !isNaN(yNumeric) && xNumeric > yNumeric
        || (isNaN(xNumeric) || isNaN(yNumeric)) && x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (!isNaN(xNumeric) && !isNaN(yNumeric) && xNumeric < yNumeric
        || (isNaN(xNumeric) || isNaN(yNumeric)) && x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Which translates as "if the compared contents are numeric, compare their numeric values OR if one of them is not, compare them as strings".

Approach to compare dates would be the same - you'd first converted the content to a date object (roughly `var xDate = new Date(x.innerHTML);`, which is not exhaustive though) and compared the date objects; checking if a variable is a valid date object is a bit harder hough, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353684/8555393) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5812220/8555393) SO questions.