# Compare date passed to new Date() with the date returned by new Date();

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a date is valid. If I pass 31/02/2018 to new Date it will return Tue Mar 03 1987 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) as 31/02/2018 is not a real date. So how can I compare the passed date with the return date of new Date? or am I going about this the wrong way altogether.

```
function isDateValid() {
    var dob = "31/02/1994",
        isValidDate = false;

    var reqs = dob.split("/"),
        day = reqs[0],
        month = reqs[1],
        year = reqs[2];

    var birthday = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

    if (birthday === "????") {
        isValidDate = true;
    }

    return isValidDate;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. I left your code unchanged and stuck to your original request.

```js
function isDateValid() {
    var dob = "31/02/2018",
        isValidDate = false;

    var reqs = dob.split("/"),
        day = reqs[0],
        month = reqs[1],
        year = reqs[2];

    var birthday = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
    
    if (+year  === birthday.getFullYear()&&
        +day   === birthday.getDate()    &&
        +month === birthday.getMonth() + 1) {
        isValidDate = true;
    }

    return isValidDate;
}

console.log(isDateValid());
```

Comment: Welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last day of each month by doing this;

```
var lastDay = new Date(month, year, 0).getDate();
```

In your case;

```
function isDateValid(date){
    var isValidDate = false;

    var reqs = date.split("/"),
        day = reqs[0],
        month = reqs[1],
        year = reqs[2],
        lastDay = new Date(month, year, 0).getDate();

    if(day > 0 && day <= lastDay)
        isValidDate = true;

    return isValidDate;
}
```

Comment: This is not working correctly. `isDateValid("28/02/1994")` returns `false`.

Comment: Sorry, it was checking if it was the last day of the month, now it checks if it's lower or equal to that day

Comment: `isDateValid("0/0/1")` returns true. Well, but that is just javascript...

Comment: You are right. I guess I meant `isDateValid("1/0/0")`.