# Invalid date not returning as invalid in IE

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

I am using browser date function. I have input like 13/77/7777 which is a invalid date. I do like

```
new Date('13/77/7777').getTime();
```

This returns NAN in FF and chrome but in IE it gives a number back. How do i fix this issue.

Comment: What number comes back? Is it a different number/date each time? [Might want to take a look at this article](https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings)

Comment: I get value back like 953269200000 instead of NAN

Comment: Is that JavaScript code? Since people come on Stack Overflow from backgrounds in many languages, I think it’s better to state it precisely and also include the relevant language tag.

Comment: Parsing of non–standard strings is implementation dependent, which means you might get anything. So avoid the built–in parser and manually parse strings with your own function (maybe 3 lines of code) or use a library.

Comment: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value I get with `.getTime()` in IE11 is `183289406400000`.
The date itself comes back as `March 18, 7778`.

This is because, quite maddeningly, IE11 is parsing `13/77/7777` in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and coming up with the result of "Month 13 and Day 77 of the Year 7777" which (frustratingly and yet unsurprisingly) works out to `March 18, 7778` (if you add 13 months and 77 days to `January 1, 7777`).

Given that a quick google search turned up no results for any polyfills for the `Date` constructor in IE11, I suspect the most reasonable fix would be to sanity-check the string before trying to parse the date with the constructor.

With the caveat that while it's probably not as efficient (or as accurate) as it could be, it should serve as a reasonable example to help you get started. Something like this should do:

```js
function isValidDateString(s) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof s !== "string") {
        return false; // not a string, exit.
    }

    var parts = s.split("/");

    if (parts.length !== 3) {
        return false; // unexpected number of slashes. exit.
    }

    var d31 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12];
    var d30 = [4, 6, 9, 11];

    var mm = parseInt(parts[0]);
    var dd = parseInt(parts[1]);
    var yyyy = parseInt(parts[2]);

    // empirical testing in Chrome & IE11 to get this value. YMMV.
    var maxYear = 275760;

    var isValidYear = !isNaN(yyyy) && yyyy <= maxYear;

    var isDivisbleBy4 = (yyyy % 4 === 0);
    var isDivisbleBy100 = (yyyy % 100 === 0);
    var isDivisbleBy400 = (yyyy % 400 === 0);
    var isLeapYear = (isDivisbleBy4 && !isDivisbleBy100) || isDivisbleBy400;

    var isValidMonth = !isNaN(mm) && (mm >= 1 && mm <= 12);
    if (!isValidMonth) {
        return false;
    }

    var maxDaysInMonth = 28;

    if (d31.indexOf(mm) > -1) {
        maxDaysInMonth = 31;
    } else if (d30.indexOf(mm) > -1) {
        maxDaysInMonth = 30;
    } else if (isLeapYear) {
        maxDaysInMonth = 29;
    }

    var isValidDay = !isNaN(dd) && (dd > 0 && dd <= maxDaysInMonth);
    if (!isValidDay) {
        return false;
    }

    return isValidMonth && isValidDay && isValidYear;
}

var testsThatShouldFail = [
    '13/77/7777', // lousy Smarch weather!
    '2/29/2018',
    '9/12/275761',
    '4/31/2016',
    '6/35/2019',
];

var testsThatShouldPass = [
    '1/1/1900',
    '2/29/2000',
    '2/29/2016',
    '9/12/275760',
    '8/16/2018',
];

console.log('should fail', testsThatShouldFail.map(isValidDateString));
console.log('should pass', testsThatShouldPass.map(isValidDateString));
```

Comment: If the question really was "how to validate a date", the there are [*many good answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+validate+a+date) already. This answer is very long winded, it really only needs about 4 lines of code: split into parts, use the Date constructor, see if the month has changed. If not, it's valid. Otherwise, it isn't. ;-) See [*How to validate a date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date/5812341#5812341)