# How to check if the DateTime matches the required format while using HTML DateTime-Local

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, date, datetime-local

I am developing a web application in which I have multiple HTML fields of type `datetime-local`. Users should provide the value for this in the following format:

```
2022-04-01T14:44:53
```

Since it is a user-selectable field sometimes users are omitting final seconds for this field. Date time with missing seconds value:

```
2022-04-01T14:44:53 //missing final seconds :53
```

Is there any way I can validate the same in JavaScript? I am developing the application using `Nuxtjs/Vuejs`. Better if there is any way I can add the validation within my HTML element itself.

Following is my HTML element:

```
<input
v-model="specificDateTime"
type="datetime-local"
class="form-control"
title="Set Event Time"
value="2022-04-01T10:00:00"
step="1"
>
```

Please let me know if there is any possibility to validate `datetime-local` at the HTML level itself based on the format. If not how can I do the same in my JavaScript?

If I provide empty values to `hour/minutes` then I get the error message but if I make the seconds as empty then I do not get the error. How to make the seconds field to be required so if the user provide empty values then it should throw the error.

Comment: [*How to validate a date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812220/how-to-validate-a-date)