# Regex Specific Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, date, format

I was wondering if somebody could point me to a regex code that validates for this: ####/##/##

Example: `1990/05/25`

The second number `0` can only be `0` or `1` and the number `2` and only be `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`.  Other than that all other numbers in this set are allowed (0-9).

The code should validate that there is only 9 or 10 characters in total including the slashes.

Comment: Do you only want to validate the string or also validate the date itself? For instance, `2013/02/29` is not a valid date. Also, very important: what (programming) language are you using?

Comment: Do you mean the character in position 0 can only be 0 or 1 and character in position 2 can only be 0,1,2 or 3?

Comment: @Jerry Well yes I am basically validating that it is a date in this format 2013/05/29  If its possible I I would prefer if it also allows 2013/5/29

Comment: @Norman  The character with number 0 -  Sorry should of been more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to validate this format, you can use a regex like...

```
^\d{1,4}\/[01]?\d\/[0-3]\d$
```

I tested it a bit on some dates [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/mD3aE4).

This will match:

```
1990/01/01
2012/13/34
2013/1/39
9999/0/00
```

But reject:

```
23121/32/44
12/05/013
013/000/00
```

If you want to reject invalid dates as well such as `2013/02/29`, you can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51224/1578604).

Comment: 12235/23/2/ passed the validation.  So it can't serve my purpose :(

Comment: @Bagzli Did you include the anchors (`^` and `$`)? I added them a bit later.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the new code and it seems to validate for all bad cases I can think of.  I think I used your old code when I tried it the first time.

Comment: @Bagzli Yes, sorry about that, I wasn't thinking that you might have extra characters before and after the date initially. ^^; Glad that I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this (edit following Jerry)

```
[0-2][0-9]{3,3}/[0|1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]
```

Mess about with the {a,b} notation to change the length of the general digits, it means between a and b of the preceding expression inclusive. It's unclear in your question where you want the digit flexibility to be.

E.g. to emit 2013/5/29, use

```
 [0-2][0-9]{3,3}/[0|1]{0,1}[0-9]/[0-3][0-9]
```

Comment: I tried typing this in: 12235/23/2/ and it said it is valid.  I really need it to check that the code is 9 or 10 digits long and to only allow specific numbers in certain spots as described in my question.

Comment: That fails on my regex parser (Boost C++) using either regex I've given. Which parser are you using?

Comment: using this on asp.net (c#) ValidationSummary with CustomValidator

Comment: @Bathsheba This will not allow any year after 1999, like 2000 or 2013 because of the `[0|1]` at the start :(. Also, `[01]` is the same as `[0|1]`.

Comment: I don't think your regex parser is doing what you want it to do. Why not test it with something simple like [0-9]? i.e. one digit.

Answer (score 1):

For all things regex I have found this website to be an invaluable resource.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Specifically this page should get you what you need and contains a full explanation of how to go about validating date input format (not value) via Regular Expressions.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

would match

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```