# Extract a date from a text

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, date, text

I'd like to extract an invoice date from the text of an invoice.

I'll have a string with the entire invoice text, and I don't know where the date is in the text or how the date is formatted.

How would I attack this problem? I am using C#.

Comment: This question isn't answerable in it's current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?  It would only handle one specific format but the regex can be adjusted for other formats.

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"[01]?\d[/-][0123]?\d[/-]\d{2}");
Match m = rg.Match(string);
m.ToString();
```

Here is a question with a bunch of date regexes that may help. [Regular Expression to match valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates/51231#51231)

Answer (score 0):

Learn and use regular expressions - >

[Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) for C#

[Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) A good place to test your regex

[Regex Matching](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) How to get the matched value back from Regex in C#

You'll need to hande different format possibilities.