# regular expression to find DD Month YYYY from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string 
          `Born
          (1970-07-30) 30 July 1970 (age 43)
          London, UK`

I need to get the sub string `30 July 1970` from this. Like wise for any month, ie. the DOB may only  change .

Can any one please help me with a regular expression for this ?

Comment: provide your code first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match valid dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates)

Comment: Please show what you have done

Comment: Always how what you have tried as this will help you in learning from self and best result for long term. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var string = "Born (1970-07-30) 30 July 1970 (age 43) London, UK";

var pattern = /\s(\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]+\s\d{4})\s/

//fetch all matches back into an array
var result = string.match(pattern);

alert(result[1]);
```

<kbd>**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PKvy/1/)**</kbd>

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<kbd>**[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/mNFfeaT2_jT9Yj7c)**</kbd>

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with regex, there is a common enough pattern to just pull it apart...

```
var string = "Born (1970-07-30) 30 July 1970 (age 43) London, UK";
string = string.substring(string.indexOf(")") + 1);//" 30 July 1970 (age 43) London, UK"
string = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("("));//" 30 July 1970 "
string = string.trim();//"30 July 1970"
//string = "30 July 1970"
```

Comment: there is a potential here that the number of spaces might change after the `(` and or before the `)`. "potentially" anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

If they're always formatted like this you don't need a regular expression. You can use split and slice.

```
var textDate = yourString.split(' ').slice(2, 5).join(' ');
```

Comment: much better than mine ;-)

Comment: Actually, [mine is faster](http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substring-123)

Comment: @musefan how fast is it compared with the regex? do you have any perf data?

Comment: I think he's updating the test now. Just ran it and got an error. I'm curious about the results as well.

Comment: @milkshake: trying to do that now but it complain about your code, cant see why as I used your JS fiddle code which obvs works

Comment: @milkshake: Seems to work when using `result[0]`... [the test has been updated](http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substring-123) - I still win!

Comment: I wonder what he's going to do with ALL that extra time he saves. =p

Comment: Build a house or paint a self portrait?

Comment: @musefan very good :D