# YYYY/MM/DD date format regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use regular expression for matching  these date formats as below in C#.

1. YYYY/MM/DD  2013/11/12
2. YYYY/M/DD   2013/5/11
3. YYYY/MM/D   2013/10/5
4. YYYY/M/D    2013/5/6

I have tried some regular expressions but they can't match the 4 date formats.
such as

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

Comment: you need to match 0 or 1 instance of `0` so you need a `?` after `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates) to get an idea of the compexity of regex and validating dates. so i would use

```
\d{4}(?:/\d{1,2}){2}
```

then in c# do whatever to validate the match. while it can be done, you'll be spending a lot of time trying to achieve it, though there is a regex in that post that with a bit of fiddling  supposedly will validate dates in regex, but it is a scary looking regex

Comment: Can you explain as to why you're using ?: it would work otherwise as well, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
^\d{4}[-/.]\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2}$
```

The curly braces `{}` give the number allowed.  E.g., `\d{1,2}` means either one or two digits.

Comment: @Michael Happy to help!  In case you haven't seen it, [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) site is a reference I rely on for regex details.

Answer (score 0):

You may need more than that to match date. Try this:

```
(19|20)\d\d([-/.])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((([0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]))\-((0[13578])|(1[02]))\-((0[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[01])))|((([0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]))\-((0[469])|11)\-((0[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(30)))|(((000[48])|([0-9][0-9](([13579][26])|([2468][048])))|([0-9][1-9][02468][048])|([1-9][0-9][02468][048]))\-02\-((0[1-9])|([12][0-9])))|((([0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]))\-02\-((0[1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-8])))
```

This is the regex for `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

You can replace `-` with `\/` for `yyyy/MM/dd`...

Tested working perfect..

Comment: This hurts my eyes. ;)

Comment: Doesn't work for 1900-02-29 and 2100-02-29 which are not valid dates.  Also, you could replace [0-9] with \d making your regex expression much shorter

Answer (score 0):

Ajit's regex is nearer to perfect but leaks the evaluation of the leap years that end with 12 and 16. Here is the correction to be just perfect

```
((([0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]))-((0[13578])|(1[02]))-((0[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[01])))|((([0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]))-((0[469])|11)-((0[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(30)))|(((000[48])|([0-9]0-9)|([0-9][1-9][02468][048])|([1-9][0-9][02468][048])|([0-9]0-9)|([0-9][1-9][13579][26])|([1-9][0-9][13579][26]))-02-((0[1-9])|([12][0-9])))|((([0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]))-02-((0[1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-8])))
```

Comment: Doesn't work for 1900-02-29 and 2100-02-29 which are not valid dates. Also, you could replace [0-9] with \d making your regex expression much shorter

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This accepts all four patterns

```
@"\d{4}[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"
```