# Date Regular Expression in UNIX

Tags: regex, date, unix

I'm trying to write a regular expression to validate a date in **Unix**. The regex that matches a date in the usual format is   mm/dd/yy

For example, it should match 03/20/98 or 11/08/89 but not 13/40/99

I managed to find the answer on [Regular Expression to match valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates) but the expression is not working on UNIX.

Below regex is not working when I tried to validate the date

echo '12/01/2014' | grep '^((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))/)|(((0[469])|([469])|(11))/)|((2|02)/))[/]\d{4}$|^\d{4}$'

**No matches**

echo '2/1/2014' | grep '^((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))/)|(((0[469])|([469])|(11))/)|((2|02)/))[/]\d{4}$|^\d{4}$'

**No matches**

Comment: Not a great date format. Europeans logically prefer dd/mm/yy,  and computer people prefer yyyymmdd (because it will sort without any extra work). More importantly, your description "not working" doesn't give us anything to help you with. Edit your question to include the regular expr you're using,  sample inputs and output, plus the error messages or other evidence that indicate it is not working. I didn't downvote, but if you can't improve the quality of your question, I will ;-) . .... Good luck!

Comment: to add to what shellter is saying, both mm/dd/yy and dd/mm/yy are to be avoided as much as possible because they both allow dates which are valid in either format ( is 02/03/14 the third of February or the second of march!)  YYYY-MM-DD not only aligns chronological and lexographical order, it also avoids this ambiguity ( until some culture is dumb enough to start writing YYYY-DD-MM at least :) )

Comment: +1 for adding sample data. Seems overkill. and as DanF points out below, you're still not catching whether it is as valid date for its month. Do really need that percision? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several regular expression formats;  Probably you're trying to use standard or extended regular expressions, but using a PCRE from the linked answer.

And as the accepted answer there suggests, date validation is not easy with regular expressions alone.  If an incomplete validation is acceptable to you, this simple one seems to pass my tests ( and note the use of `egrep` and not just `grep` for the `(a|b)` syntax:

```
for date in `cat dates.txt` ; do 
if (echo $date |\
    egrep '^(1[0-2]|0[0-9])[-/]([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])[-/][0-9]{2}' > /dev/null
); then 
       echo "$date is valid"
   else 
       echo "$date is invalid" 
   fi
done
```

Gives me:

```
01-01-48 is valid
13-01-99 is invalid
02-30-03 is valid
03-32-14 is invalid
```

But, as many have said on the other thread, the regular expression to verify number of days in a month and leap years becomes complicated fast.  This regex only verifies that each part of the date is valid in itself - it doesn't verify that the day of the month exist in the month.  That's why it thinks `02-30-03` is a valid date.

Comment: I tried with given regex but its not working either


`echo '01-01-48' | egrep '^(1[0-2]|0[0-9])[-/]([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])[-/][0-9]{2}'`

Comment: `$ echo '01-01-48' | egrep '^(1[0-2]|0[0-9])[-/]([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])[-/][0-9]{2}'`
 => `01-01-48` `echo $?` => `0`
Works just fine on my mac.  What Operating system are you on?

Comment: Worked for me on GNU egrep as well.  What system are you on where it doesn't work?  Some distos ( CentOS ) don't install the full versions of things, a point of confusion for me.

Comment: egrep or grep doesn't work on this SunOS.

`SunOS <boxname> 5.10 Generic_147440-27 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise`