# I need patern to validate a concret string

Tags: php

I need a function to validate any string provided in GET['date'] parameter.

The function will return true if the string provided is in format "j-n-Y", and is a date between today and the future.

Examples:

http://mysite.org/index.php?date=iwhechiuhwe will return false.

http://mysite.org/index.php?date=13-5-2017 will return true.

http://mysite.org/index.php?date=13-5-2010 will return false.

http://mysite.org/index.php?date=19-5-2014 will return true.

Comment: So, what did you try and what was the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match valid dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates)

Comment: Date validation is a solved problem.  Search in the search box to find existing solutions to your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$dateResult = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', $_GET['date']);`

This method in PHP's DateTime class returns false if it couldn't create a date object from the requested format and given string.

A further test to verify that the given date was today or future (if `$dateResult` is not already false):

```
$now = strtotime('Y-m-d', time());
$isValid = $dateResult->getTimestamp() >= $now;
```

Comment: ¡Thank you! It works :) The users that have given downvote and marked this as too abroad, ¿really? ¿Is that so difficult to answer?

Comment: I don't think too broad is a valid close reason. It's a question that has probably come up before, which will be why it was downvoted. But the linked question in the comments above didn't have a good solution.