# How to check date in dd-Mon-yyyy format in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, string

At First I use to pass data to action class from java script But I want to do in java script How to do?

Jsp java script:

```
$('#nwr_fa_dob').keypress(function(event)
       {
          $('#nwr_fa_gender').attr('disabled',false);
         var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode :event.which);
         var dob= $('#nwr_fa_dob').val();
         if(keycode == '13' || keycode =='40')
         {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",              
                dataType: "json",
                url: "dob_details",
                data: {dob:dob},        
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#nwr_fa_dob').val(response.dob);
                    if($('#nwr_fa_dob').val()==null || $('#nwr_fa_dob').val()=='')
                    {
                        alert("You Will Give Age or DateFormat of dd-MMM-yyyy(Ex : 18-Mar-1990)");
                        $('#nwr_fa_dob').val('');
                        $('#nwr_fa_dob').focus();
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#nwr_fa_dob').val(response.dob);
                        $('#nwr_fa_gender').focus();
                        }
                    }
                });
            return false;
            }
         if(keycode=='38'){
             $('#nwr_fa_fsname').focus();
             return false;
             }
         });
```

Java Code:

```
public String dob_fetchdate() {
        try {
            if (dob.length() == 11) {
                Date dat = ymd.parse(dob);
                if (ymd.format(dat).equals(dob)) {
                    dob = dob;
                } else {
                dob = null;
                }
            } else if (dob.length() == 10) {
                dob = null;
            } else if (dob.length() == 2) {
                String date = DateNow.substring(7, 11);
                String year = String.valueOf(Long.valueOf(date)
                        - Long.valueOf(dob));
                dob = DateNow.substring(0, 7).concat(year);
            } else {
                dob = null;
            }
            return "success";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Dob Error =" + ex);
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) is certainly the reference API for date manipulations in javascript.
Here is an example of how it could be used in your case :

```
var userDateString = "30-Aug-2014";
var dateFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY";
var myMoment = moment(userDateString, dateFormat);
if (myMoment.isValid()) {
    alert ("Date is valid !");
} else {
    alert ("Invalid date !");
}
```

It can also tell you what is wrong with the date you typed.

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done with Regex in javascript

```
    var date="01-01-1944";
    var pattern = /[0-9]{2}[-]{1}[0-9]{2}[-]{1}[0-9]{4}/i;

    if(pattern.test(date)) {
        var dateParts = date.split("-");
        // You can do the range checking here
        console.log(dateParts[0]);
        console.log(dateParts[1]);
        console.log(dateParts[2]);
    }
```

To know more about Regex in JS follow [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)

Also read answers of this question [Regular Expression to match valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates).