# How to check entered value in input tag is matching with specific date format like "MM/dd/YYYY" in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to check given value is matching with specific date format like "MM/dd/YYYY"

Ts file

```
onValChange(event: Date) {
    const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
    const val = datePipe.transform(event, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    this.writeValue(moment(event));
  }
```

Html file

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm requiredV" [(ngModel)]="dateValue"
     placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="dateField" id="dateField" ngbDatepicker
     #dateFieldngb="ngbDatepicker" [required]="isRequired"
     [ngClass]="{'isUntouched':formName.submitted}" (ngModelChange)="onValChange($event)"
     (keypress)="allow_only_numbers($event)" (click)="dateFieldngb.toggle()" />
```

Can you please tell me how to check entered value is matching with this specific format or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use an external library to control dates.

https://momentjs.com

This library provides a function valid. You can implement this function like this

```
moment(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY').isValid()
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me an idea to do this

Comment: Maybe you must limit the length to 10 characters, or use a regular expression to check the string

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data using date pipe, please check given reference.

[Angular Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either by using a library or writing a custom function

1. Library - [moment-js](https://momentjs.com/)

   Example:

```js
moment("2010 13",           "YYYY MM").isValid();     // false (not a real month)
moment("2010 11 31",        "YYYY MM DD").isValid();  // false (not a real day)
moment("2010 2 29",         "YYYY MM DD").isValid();  // false (not a leap year)
moment("2010 notamonth 29", "YYYY MMM DD").isValid(); // false (not a real month name)
```

Referred from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30219684/9848549) thread.

---

2. Custom function using Regular expression

```js
var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;

if(!(date_regex.test(testDate))){
  return false;
}
```

Referred from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) thread